# Starting Skype breaks Internet connection, LAN connection staying alive

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, troubleshooting, skype, lan, wireless-networking

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and I've just installed Skype. Whenever I try to sign into Skype, my Internet connection breaks. I remain connected to my wireless LAN but can't connect to the Internet.

The login hangs a while, I can't go anywhere in a browser or even ping a known host. The only thing that helps is uninstalling then restarting the computer.

I've uninstalled Skype for now, but does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

- Install wireshark, and monitor what happens when skype is started
- check log messages -> grep -i [interface used for internet] /var/log/*

Also, since you mentioned that you stay connected to the LAN, I presume you are using something like pppd to connect to the internet. Check `plog` to see what happens.

Comment: I'll definitely try that.

Comment: So, finally what was the solution?